# how i can solve the erorrs cpp.exe: error: main.cpp: No such file or directory cpp.exe: fatal error: no input files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Here is json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe сборка активного файла",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "main.cpp",
                "-o",
                "main.exe"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "компилятор: C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    
}
```

Comment: I believe the error means `main.cpp` is not in the current folder.

Comment: please use the body of the quesiton to explain details of your question. Where is the error in the title from? When you invoke the compiler? When you run the executable? The question is rather unclear

Comment: `C:\\MinGW\\bin\\cpp.exe` should probably be `C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe` but that won't fix the missing source file problem.

Comment: Follow the manual [Using GCC with MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: This is a spot that may be the problem: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson) you may want to use `"${workspaceFolder}\\*.cpp"` instead of `main.cpp` or if you have only 1 file `"${workspaceFolder}\\main.cpp"`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!just need choose a correct output file folder like c:\user... for main.exe